# Typescript discriminated union with generic, unsound type narrowing

Tags: typescript, generics

The following code successfully compiles using Typescript 3.5.3 but it seems like it should not be allowed and I was wondering why it successfully compiles. I have created a type `A` which has a field `a` and a generic function `t` parametrized on `X` that takes in an argument that is the discriminate union of the generic `X` and the type `A`. The `'a' in a` guard inside of the function `t` seems to be narrowing the type of `a` to be `A`, however, you could imagine another type `B` with a different field `a` that would pass this check.

```
type A = {"a": string}
type B = {"a": number}

function t<X>(a: A | X, f: (x:X) => string): string {
  if ('a' in a) {
    return a.a;
  } else {
    return f (a);
  }
}
```

Furthermore, I can call this function like so:

```
let a : A = {"a": "hi"};
let f = (x:B) => {
  return x.a + " a string";
}
let tmpa = t(a, f); // has static type string and correct dynamic type string
let b: B = {"a": 5};
let tmpb = t(b, f); // has static type string but dynamic type number
```

I understand that Typescript's type system is purposefully unsound, but I couldn't figure out why this example is allowed to be unsound. Any insights would be appreciated.

Comment: The `in` type guard is generally pretty unsound .. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAiAhigXFAzsATgJYB2A5gL4CwAUKJFAEILIoBGWUxArgLasT4q1GgBsIwXF1ZNESGlCitsARgA0UeVDQqaQmgDMuxAMbBCAe2JRgEPAAo0S2FAA+jAJTJNhfVDvoUKBItVk85agUFY0scczEAOhFzUgdWeLRPAHpM63AIABMtHFwCElJ1Vi4Jbj4BTXIoCBEcaHDIjQioIT1aW2A7HCkGdwBuGnHqIA  It's useful but easily lets run-time errors occur.

Comment: Closest thing to a canonical answer is probably [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/15256#discussion_r154843152)